# Linux - How can I copy text by selecting it, and automatically send it to an application I choose?

Tags: linux-mint

I'm browsing the web searching for some information and copying some of them in kile for LaTeX editing.

The way I do this is selecting with the mouse the text i'm interested in, move to the workspace in which I have Kile, and click mouse wheel so that the text is copied.

I'd like to automatize the task: selecting parts i'm and having them automatically sent to kile, so that I haven't to change workspace or click the mouse wheel. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You want to somehow have any text you select magically pasted into a different application? I don't think that is possible.

Comment: I have never heard of anything that'll do this either. By highlighting, you aren't actually executing a command, so there's no action to attach a script or application or anything to.

Comment: @Simkill well, highlighting actually copies to the X clipboard so it _might_ conceivably be possible.

Comment: Oh I suppose you can highlight and right click to paste in prompt can't you so yeah I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you could try [parcellite](http://parcellite.sourceforge.net/?page_id=2/) it says it in version 1.1 it supports auto paste via the xdotool

or perhaps just script something yourself with  xdotool.
[like so](http://thecodecentral.com/2012/07/27/use-mouse-buttons-to-perform-copy-paste-in-ubuntu)

Hope that helps...